# whm/cpanel server install web folder location

Tags: linux, rhel5

on a whm/cpanel server install, where is the hostname web folder located. ex. if hostname is svr1.server.com where is the web folder for that. i checked /root/public_html/ but that's not it

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember offhand, but type `httpd -S` and look for the configuration file, I think it's /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf or similar. Copy the file path name type:
`grep "DocumentRoot" /that/full/path/name` - it should tell you where the files are.